# security trimmed nested top navigation sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, global-navigation

Is it possible to achieve security trimmed nested top navigation SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by breaking the inheritance of the respective pages.

If the user don't have permission to the page then they will not see the link it. (Assuming the top navigation is out of the box)

Comment: Don't understand, In site settings>navigation I cant add a heading within a heading for global navigation. Hence cant produce a nested navigation.

Comment: You asked for security trimming and based on that I answered. My answer is specific to hiding links where users dont have permissions.

Comment: I also asked NESTED ;)